# Improve performance of math function applied to arrays

Tags: python, performance, array, numpy

This block of code is already somewhat optimized thanks to [some](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21269833/68063) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838278/improve-performance-of-function-without-parallelization) given over at Stack Overflow. In the last question I made ([Improve performance of function without parallelization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21838278/improve-performance-of-function-without-parallelization)) the code was marginally improved but I later had to re-write a little bit of it and the changes proposed didn't apply anymore.

I'm looking at optimizing this block of code without resorting to parallelization, other than that I'm pretty much open to using any package out there.

I think this is perhaps the correct site to post this since it's really more of a question about how can I improve my code rather than something not working with it.

Here's the MWE (minimum working example):

```
import numpy as np
import timeit

def random_data(N):
    # Generate some random data.
    return np.random.uniform(0., 10., N)

# Data lists.
array1 = np.array([random_data(4) for _ in range(1000)])
array2 = np.array([random_data(4) for _ in range(2000)])

def func():
    lst = []

    for elem in array1:

        # Define factors.
        a_01, a_11 = max(elem[1], 1e-10), max(elem[3], 1e-10)
        a_02, a_12 = array2[:,1], array2[:,3]
        # Combine the factors defined above.
        a_0 = a_01**2 + a_02**2
        a_1 = a_11**2 + a_12**2
        Bs, Cs = -0.5/a_0, -0.5/a_1

        # Perform operations.
        A = 1./(np.sqrt(a_0*a_1))
        B = Bs*(elem[0]-array2[:,0])**2
        C = Cs*(elem[2]-array2[:,2])**2
        ABC = A*np.exp(B+C)

        lst.append(max(ABC.sum(), 1e-10))

    return lst

# Time function.
func_time = timeit.timeit(func, number=10000)
print func_time
```

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What problem are you solving?

Comment: @GarethRees it's a bit hard to explain since this is a tiny part of a much larger code I'm working on. In short, it calculates the probability that each element of `array1` "belongs" (or "is related") to `array2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't make much improvement on this, sorry. Since you didn't explain what the code is supposed to do, there was no opportunity for algorithmic insight, so the only changes I could make were purely mechanical transformations with no understanding.

One obvious thing to do is to replace:

```
def random_data(N):
    # Generate some random data.
    return np.random.uniform(0., 10., N)

array1 = np.array([random_data(4) for _ in range(1000)])
array2 = np.array([random_data(4) for _ in range(2000)])
```

with

```
array1 = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (1000, 4))
array2 = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (2000, 4))
```

which is about 50 times faster. (Note that you don't have to write `0.` and `10.` here: if you read the documentation for [`numpy.random.uniform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) you'll see that the parameters *low* and *high* have type "*float*", so which whatever values you provide will be coerced to floats.)

Other observations are:

- Operations on `array2` don't depend on `elem` and so can be hoisted out of the loop.
- It's quicker to make one call to [`numpy.split`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) than to slice `array2` four times.
- It's quicker to call [`numpy.square`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.square.html) than use the expression `A ** 2`.
- The multiplication by `-0.5` can be saved until after `B+C`, reducing the number of operations.
- A single division `X / Y` is cheaper than calculating a reciprocal `A = 1 / Y` and multiplying `A * X`.

Applying all of these, my best effort is as follows:

```
def func2():
    lst = []

    epsilon = 1e-10

    P = np.split(array1, 4, axis=1)
    P[1] = np.square(np.maximum(P[1], epsilon))
    P[3] = np.square(np.maximum(P[3], epsilon))
    P = np.hstack(P)

    Q = np.split(array2, 4, axis=1)
    Q[1] = np.square(Q[1])
    Q[3] = np.square(Q[3])

    for elem in P:
        a_0 = elem[1] + Q[1]
        a_1 = elem[3] + Q[3]

        B = np.square(elem[0] - Q[0]) / a_0
        C = np.square(elem[2] - Q[2]) / a_1
        ABC = np.exp(-0.5 * (B + C)) / np.sqrt(a_0 * a_1)

        lst.append(max(ABC.sum(), epsilon))

    return lst
```

This is about 25% faster than your code:

```
>>> timeit(func2, number=100) / timeit(func, number=100)
0.7512780299658295
```

For comparison, here's the fully-vectorized version of your code:

```
def func3():
    epsilon = 1e-10
    P = array1.reshape(-1, 1, 4)
    Q = array2
    R = np.square(np.maximum(P[...,(1,3)], epsilon))
    S = np.square(Q[:,(1,3)])
    T = R + S
    U = np.square(P[...,(0,2)] - Q[:,(0,2)]) / T
    V = np.exp(-0.5 * U.sum(axis=2)) / np.sqrt(T.prod(axis=2))
    return np.maximum(V.sum(axis=1), epsilon)
```

This is about 25% slower than your code because it's O(*n*<sup>2</sup>) in space as well as time, but it's substantially simpler, so it might be a better place to start when making algorithmic improvements.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Gareth, I'll try it right now and report back the results. I'm sorry I can't go into much detail but my actual code is _really_ large, I did comment on what this block does in any case (right below your comment in the original question)

Comment: @Gabriel: I was hoping for a more technical explanation like "this computes the radial basis function kernel" or whatever.

Comment: Gareth this article http://goo.gl/7krj3L can give you an idea of what I'm after, particularly eq. 4. Sorry I can't be more succinct but it really is quite a large issue to be able to discuss it here.

Comment: @Gabiel: Thank you, that's more like it. I was wondering why the input arrays seemed to consist of multiple kinds of interleaved data.

Answer (score 5):

Well, some things I noticed:

```
    # Define factors.
    a_01, a_11 = max(elem[1], 1e-10), max(elem[3], 1e-10)
    a_02, a_12 = array2[:,1], array2[:,3]
```

`a_02` and `a_12` are static across the loop, no need to redefine them every time. `a_01` and `a_12` could be defined array-wise using `np.maximum`:

```
a_01 = np.maximum(array1[:,1], np.array(1e-10 for _ in xrange(len(array1))
a_11 = np.maximum(array1[:,3], np.array(1e-10 for _ in xrange(len(array1))
```

However, these are trivial improvements; function call overhead is often blamed for much in the Python optimisation world, but there is no way that removing 2n calls to max will improve things here. With that said, following the static data path further, we come across an instance of

```
a_0 = a_01**2 + a_02**2
a_1 = a_11**2 + a_12**2
```

If we instead define

```
a_022 = a_02**2
a_122 = a_12**2
```

at the beginning of the function, we can avoid n multiplications by replacing later occurrences of `a_02**2` with `a_022` (and likewise for `a_12`), which reduces the running time of the program by about 5% on my machine. That isn't too impressive, though I'm sure you should be able to knock that down a fair bit by doing more thing using numpy functions. However, my numpy skills evaporate when it comes to 2d arrays, so I can't help.

It is worth mentioning that the algorithm you are using is `O(n^2)` at least, so wouldn't get your hopes up too high. Otherwise, I'd recommend looking at Cython as this seems like a problem it would excel at, though you've mentioned that parallelism isn't an option, so I assume using C extensions won't be either. However, if it is, I think you will find great time savings there.

This was the final code I came up with:

```
def func2():
    lst = []
    # Define factors.
    a_02, a_12 = array2[:,1], array2[:,3]
    a_022 = a_02 ** 2
    a_122 = a_12 ** 2
    e10 = np.array([1e-10 for _ in xrange(len(array1))])
    a_01 = np.maximum(array1[:,1], e10)
    a_11 = np.maximum(array1[:,3], e10)
    for i, elem in enumerate(array1):
        # Combine the factors defined above.
        a_0 = a_01[i]**2 + a_022
        a_1 = a_11[i]**2 + a_122
        Bs, Cs = -0.5/a_0, -0.5/a_1
        # Perform operations.
        A = 1./(np.sqrt(a_0*a_1))
        B = Bs*(elem[0]-array2[:,0])**2
        C = Cs*(elem[2]-array2[:,2])**2
        ABC = A*np.exp(B+C)
        lst.append(max(ABC.sum(), 1e-10))
    return lst

N = 100
func_time = timeit.timeit(func, number=N)
print "Original\t", func_time / N
print "-" * 50

func2_time = timeit.timeit(func2, number=N)
print "Revision 1\t", func2_time / N
print "Improvement\t", str(int((func_time - func2_time) / func_time * 100)) + "%"
print "-" * 50
```

Comment: I'm getting a result of `Improvement -90015%` with this new function. Can you confirm this?

Comment: I think that might be because the indentation of the `return lst` in the original function is incorrect; I presumed that was a typo as most people don't want to exit a loop after only one iteration.

Comment: This was the exact code I tested: https://gist.github.com/bluepeppers/9080540

Comment: You are right @BluePeppers, the indent was incorrect in my original code (now fixed) With the correct code I get a ~4% improvement. Thank you very much! I'll wait a bit to see if someone else can top your code otherwise I'll mark your answer as accepted. Cheers.

Comment: Take advantage of [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and write `np.maximum(X, 1e-10)` instead of `np.maximum(X, np.array([1e-10 for _ in range(len(X))]))`